# PHP: Access Values from Array1 from inside Array2

Tags: php, arrays

I have some arrays like:

```
$Array1 = array
(
    "foo" => "foo",
    "foo2" => "foo2",
    "bar" => "bar",
    "bar2" => "bar2"
)

$Array2 = array
(
    "fooo" => "bla " . $Array1,
...
)
```

and now I want something like:

```
echo $Array2["fooo"]["foo"];
```

for "bla foo"

But I just get

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'foo' in xy.php on line 37 G

How to do that?

Comment: I don't know why you would want it but you're not gonna get the _bla_ in there: `$Array2 = array
("fooo" => $Array1);`

Comment: You can't concatenate an entire array as it was a string. You'll need something like `$Array2["fooo"] = $Array1["foo"];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it won't work the way you've done.

You may associate array2 to "fooo" directly, but can't concatenate an array to a string.

Try to do like this:

```
$Array1 = array
(
    "foo" => "foo",
    "foo2" => "foo2",
    "bar" => "bar",
    "bar2" => "bar2"
)

$Array2 = array
(
    "fooo" => $Array1,
)
```

As you can see, I've associated $Array1 directly to "fooo" index, so I'll be able to access it by:

```
echo $Array2['fooo']['foo'];
```

Answer (score 0):

use this :

```
$Array2 = array
(
    "fooo" =>array(  
            "bla " => $Array1
                   )

)
```